# C++/(MFC dummy) and pure Win MessageBox() - How to delete message queue or other way to delete existing mouse clicks / key buffer

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

(Maybe this is a beginner question for people experienced with Windows message queue handling and dialg boxes. Unfortunately this is not *my* area of expertise, so please be gracious to me.)

I have a quite simple C++ program in terms of user interface. 
It should not be a real console program of several reasons, but it runs unattended.
It is basically a MFC stub without showing a window at all. But sometimes it shows  message boxes like :

MessageBox("Question,"XX",MB_YESNO) or so.

The problem is, that, when two questions are posed after each other, sometimes Windows seems to save the mouse click or keyboard click or the user wanted to klick only once, but the hardware send two clicks. So the user has not real possibility to answer the second question, but yes or no is answered from the "ghost" click before.
(There is a word for it, but I don't know it in English. I hope, you got my point though.)

In the command line there is a fflush() for such things. How to handle it here?

I would even use a customized Messagebox, if I find somewhere ready code for it
(and I have not to write it :-)

But I thought, there might be an easy-to-use snippet to delete the message queue of the app before the next messagebox is shown. But all I know about Windows messages is that they exist ;-( 
Can anybody help me?

Comment: More probable cause is that user simply double clicks on first message box. Maybe add a 2-3 s delay before showing second message box. Actually showing such messageboxes from some hidden app is not a good idea, user can do some other thing and might accidentally click on your appearing messagebox, accepting whatever question it is showing. System tray baloons are better for that.

Comment: Yes, but here it is a different scenario: It is a wrapper starting a second app. Only in some cases some milliseconds after the start, it brings a messagebox to ask sth. Part of question here is to minimize effort. It is not the question of finding the most modern user Interface: The customer is content with msgbox, so nobody pays for more. I don't think a delay will help much, but I will try again.

Comment: I think, it really was a small delay what helped here; sorry for asking, sometimes it looks more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 1):

Philm,

Message box is a modal window, hence it has own message loop. When message box is dismissed, its message does not exist, no mouse messages.

Mouse click messages are always posted to a window under the cursor, unless GetCapture is called. 
From what you claim, you do not show any window, so no mouse messages posted in the que?

The only way to resolve your problem would be to debug your application or the test project that you write to duplicate this problem. Can you write it and post somewhere for downloading?

Comment: Thanks for the info. It has turned out, that in my case, a small sleep() really helped a lot. I have had seen the problem in other applications before, but I have not realized, that in message box it is to solve that easy.